# Spécial HTML character ( & # 39; -> quot ) in XML file

Tags: android, quote

I got an  " & # 39; " in my XML file. (it is the char code for the quot in HTML)

EX :

< desc > blabla bla **& # 39**; bla bla la. < / desc>

When i parse it with `String tmp = itemOfEvent.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()` it cut my text juste before the quot.

I got a crash with `URL.encode(tmp, "UTF-8")`

Better idea ?

Comment: it's not just special, it's *Spécial*!

Comment: Also, which language is this? is this Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution i've found was to replace bad char

```
xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll(" & #39;", " \ ' ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You say that the text is HTML encoded so try this:

```
String fixedTmp = Html.fromHtml(tmp).toString();
```

Comment: i try it doesn't change any thing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're parsing the XML file with a SAXParser? In this case, note that the 'characters()'-method can be called multiple times while parsing a single Element (as it does in your case). Try this:

```
private StringBuilder temp_val;
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
    temp_val.append(ch, start, length);
}
```

Comment: in fact, i made a big mistake : i didn't get th return of remplaceAll conction. i've try  xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("&#39;", "\'"); and that work